# Show a custom notification at the moment the app update finishes?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, objective-c++

I need to notify the user about new features of my app as soon as the app update finishes and the app is not in the foreground (i.e., it is terminated or is in the background). How do I achieve this? This scenario will happen if the app was already installed and auto-updates were on.

I achieved this on Android using `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast receiver. I've read about `NSNotificationName` in `NSNotificationCenter` in iOS but couldn't find an equivalent to `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with iOS without the app running in the background Period. Even if your app is running in the background after Appstore updates the app, your app gets killed and you don't have control over it until the user launches it for the first time.

Maybe you could try sending a silent push notification to the app to see if it responds and try to get the current app version.